# Rtf to html conversion

Tags: java, html

How to convert rtf to HTML in java javax.JEditor RTFEditorKit and HTML Editor Kit not working suggest any external third part jars or else any method i tried jodconverter tika

Comment: Why are they not working?  What have you tried?  What errors do you get?

Answer (score 0):

To convert Rtf to html [Try this](http://squallssck.github.io/blog/2013/02/25/about-how-to-convert-docx-slash-doc-slash-rtf-into-html-using-java/)

Comment: This could not be used because i run program on build where port number may change please suggest something else